# Magnetic field $\vec{A}$ as momentum potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics, classical-field-theory

I was reviewing some topics on electromagnetic field theory and I came across the following interesting assertion: the electromagnetic moment $P_{EM}$, which is defined in vacuum as:

$$P_{EM}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\int d^3r\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$$

can also we expressed for a single moving charge $q$ in the vecinity of a stationary charge $q'$ (by integrating over a volume containing $q$) as:

$$P_{EM}=kq'\vec{A}(\vec{r}',t)$$

where $\vec{A}$ is the vector potential of the charge $q$ evaluated in the position $r'$ of charge $q'$, and $k$ is a constant to determine. This expression allows us to interpret $q\vec{A}$ as a "potential momentum" that can be converted into the kinetic moment of a particle. Moreover, notice that $\vec{P}=\vec{p}+q\vec{A}$ is exactly the canonical moment we encounter in electrodynamics (i.e. Pauli equation).

I originally posted this to provide the answer later, but no matter how much I tried during the weekend I couldn't find a way to arrive to the correct expression, so I decided to open a bounty so I could get some help (since it I think this will be useful for further reference).

**Latest attempt**

Just for completeness, I'll provide my latest attempt if you want to check it out.

Let's set our inertial frame of reference at the origin O, and let $\vec{r}$ be the position of the moving charge $q$ and $\vec{r}'$ the position of the static charge $q'$.

Fields of the moving charge

$$\vec{E}_q=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

$$\vec{B}_q=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q}{r^2}\vec{v}\times\hat{r}$$

Fields for the static charge

$$\vec{E}_{q'}=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q'}{r'^2}\hat{r}'$$

$$\vec{B}_{q'}=0$$

Density of electromagnetic moment

$$g_{EM}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec{E}\times\vec{B}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}(\vec{E_q}+\vec{E_{q'}})\times\vec{B_q}$$

Substituting and developing the previous expression,

$$g_{EM}=\frac{q}{\mu_0}(\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{r}+\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q'}{r'^2}\hat{r}')\times(\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q}{r^2}\vec{v}\times\hat{r})$$

$$g_{EM}=\frac{q}{16\pi^2\epsilon_0}\left ( \frac{q}{r^4}\hat{r}\times\vec{v}\times\hat{r} + \frac{q'}{r^2r'^2}\hat{r}'\times\vec{v}\times\hat{r} \right )$$

Integrating:

$$P_{EM}=\frac{q}{16\pi^2\epsilon_0}\int_V  \left ( \frac{q}{r^4}\hat{r}\times\vec{v}\times\hat{r} + \frac{q'}{r^2r'^2}\hat{r}'\times\vec{v}\times\hat{r} \right ) dV$$

where V is a volume that contains $q$. Using the vector identity $A\times(B\times C)=(A\cdot C)B - (A\cdot B)C$ doesn't help simplifying the expression.

If we could somehow justify that the first term is zero, then we get:

$$P_{EM}=\frac{qq'}{16\pi^2\epsilon_0}\int_V  \left (\frac{1}{r^2r'^2}\hat{r'}\times\vec{v}\times\hat{r} \right ) dV$$

which can also be written as:

$$P_{EM}=\frac{q'}{4\pi\epsilon_0r'^2}\int_V  \left( \hat{r'}\times\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q}{r^2}\vec{v}\times\hat{r} \right ) dV$$

Which kind of resembles the answer we're looking for except for the fact that I have to get rid of the $r^2$ term and the first cross product, since we know that:

$$\vec{A}(\vec{r}',t)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{\vec{r}'}dV'$$

with $\vec{J}=q\vec{v}\delta(r')$. I also tried with more general coordinates but I haven't found a way to do it, and in the literature (Jackson, Griffiths, Zangwill, etc.) there's not information related to this.

Comment: Well the proof seems to be a bit harder than I thought, hence why I haven't posted the answer. I expect that in 12 more hours of trying will give me a satisfactory demonstration.